# Android apply @TargetApi() annotation globally

Tags: android

I have an Android Library Project that provides some features using API level 18. But I also want to include this library in another project with MinSDK 17. As I changed the MinSDK of the library from level 18 to 17 this lead to build errors. I have to annotate all classes/methods that uses higher level features with `@TargetApi()`.

Because I dont want to copy and paste the same lines of code in all my classes (DRY) I want to know a more generic way of setting the TargetAPI annotation, while preserving the MinSDK as defined in the Manifest.

Is there a way to globally set the TargetApi or 'inverse the annotation', so that I only have to annotate classes/methods that uses API 17 or below (opt-out vs opt-in)?

Comment: @Downvoter Again a downvote, without any usefull explanation why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as adding this to the Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="package1, package2, ..." />
```

This will lead to a successfull build. At this time the application, that uses the library must assure that only valid methods are called. For this the answer of @Marcin Orlowski can be used.